# AngularJS - custom filter, model doesn't update in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I have a custom filter set up that triggers when the user clicks on a checkbox. I use a directive to render the DOM elements, and attach a listener on the checkbox which when clicked, triggers the `filter` function that's exposed on the `$scope`.

The `$scope.model` which is used in the view should get overwritten by the result of the filter function, and the return object looks ok (e.g. the `console.log()`) but the view doesn't update. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/r3pXc/1/

**The view**:

```
<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div list-directive />
</div>
```

**The template:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
   <input type="checkbox" class="control">

   <div ng-repeat="player in model">
      Name: {{player.firstName}}, Price: {{player.price}}
   </div>
</script>
```

**The module and controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){
    $scope.model = [{ firstName: 'foo', price: 100 }, { firstName: 'bar', price: 50 }, { firstName: 'foobar', price: 0}];

    $scope.filter = function() {
        $scope.model = $filter('listFilter')($scope.model);
        console.log($scope.model);
    }
}]);
```

**The directive:**

```
app.directive('listDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            iElm.bind('click', function(e){
                var el = angular.element(e.target);

                if (el.hasClass('control')) {
                    $scope.filter();
                };
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**And the filter:**

```
app.filter('listFilter', function(){
    return function(input) {
        var results = [];

        angular.forEach(input, function(val, key){
            if (val.price != 0) {
                results.push(val);
            }
        });

        return results;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to manually call the digest cycle with `$apply()`, because I don't listen on the elements with `ng-` event handlers:

```
$scope.filter = function() {
    $scope.model = $filter('listFilter')($scope.model);
    $scope.$apply();
}
```